# Angular JS *non-SPA* SEO

Tags: ajax, angularjs, express, pug, googlebot

### Non-SPA AJAX Partials for SEO

Sadly, 101% of the Angular SEO examples assume the use of a singe-page-application (SPA). My app is not a SPA. Currently, my stack is:

- `Node/Express` - for *routing and rendering Jade templates*. The URLs are real, and don't use HTML pushstate, hash-bang or anything similar. **for this reason, url-escaped-fragment won't work for me (I don't think)**
- `Angular` for communicating with my RESTful API(s)

My problem is that my page itself only *includes* pieces that are loaded via AJAX—the rest of page is rendered server side. Node/Express is not responsible for any of this logic, Angular pulls in the data that will be in my first `h1`.

Google Bot and similar see: `<h1>{{this_unrendered_string}}</h1>` which is no good.

Has anyone come up with any clever solutions for working around this scenario?

FWIW I found a service called SEO.js that will host a rendered version of any page I pass to it. If I could just tell GoogleBot and similar "Hey, don't use this page, use *this* page instead" But I'm not entirely sure how SEO feels about a different host serving content. Maybe some trickery could work here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google have documented an approach to "Making AJAX Applications Crawlable" here. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Implementing this isn't completely simple (basically you have to run a headless browser and return the HTML snapshots in response to specially formatted requests by Google).

It's not a simple as just returning a snapshot when you detect GoogleBot, but doing it this way probably eliminates any risk of being penalized.

There are a few companies that offer this a service - I'm getting on well with this one: https://ajaxsnapshots.com - they say that Bing and Yandex (Russian search engine) support it too.

AjaxSnapshots have an API you can use to tell them when your page is ready to snapshot - you could call that after all of your client side rendering is done.

Comment: And I won't take a hit (in terms of ranking, etc.) for having the *real* location of the snapshot being on a different domain/CDN?

Comment: @couzzi - no it shouldn't, because your own webserver is all that google sees. I just launched a similar service http://crawlspa.com

Comment: I can also recommend http://www.seo4ajax.com as an alternative to ajaxsnapshots or crawlspa. It embeds a crawler to prepare snapshots in advance, it also help to detect errors. We opened the service 6 months ago and we capture currently more than 100,00 pages per day. Note: it's totally free during the beta.